# Unable to open ".ahk" file in a Sikuli program

Tags: jython, autohotkey, sikuli

Suppose I have `x.ahk`, which is an AutoHotKey file. I want to open it through my Sikuli program.

I tried the following methods:

```python
openApp("F:\\folder\\x.ahk")
```

I got the following error

```
[info] VDictProxy loaded.
[log] App.open F:\folder\x.ahk(0)
[error] App.open failed: F:\folder\x.ahk not found
```

I tried using `open()` instead

```python
open("F:\\folder\\x.ahk","r")
```

It did not throw any error from this, but it still did not open the file.

How can I launch my AutoHotKey script?

Comment: Don't know much about sikuli, bit have you tried opening it through the actual compiler? Something like: `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe "F:\folder\x.ahk"`? Alternatively, you could compile your script first and then open it.

Comment: @MCL Thanks a lot it is working well now.  Is there any command like this to close the autohotkey?

Comment: Closing it is a whole different thing. I bet sikuli is able to do that. If you're sure it's not, let me know and I'll show you how you could achieve it via command line.

Comment: One easy way of closing the script is to add these three lines on top of the script

_    #singleinstance force
    param = %1% 
    If (param = "exit")
      ExitApp
_
Then you can run it with the parameter "exit" and it will reload and close itself.

Comment: @MCL Yes I did it through sikuli but how about without using sikuli??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try running autohotkey.exe with the script name as a parameter.

Example:
If my Autohotkey.exe is in 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoHotkey"
and the script to start is
"c:\temp\1.ahk"

I would run
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoHotkey\autohotkey.exe c:\temp\1.ahk"